# Do Until in Powershell

Tags: script, powershell, serial-port

I'm connecting via serial port with powershell to a device and I'm trying to change one value until another value gets to 0. I'm using Do-Until but it just runs endlessly with the first value being changed over and over.
What I need to do is, initially I check `Value2` aka `$line1`, if it's not 0, I need to check `Value1` aka `V45`, add 10 to it, send the command to change it and reset the device, then check again `Value2` and if it's not 0 repeat.
I tried `Do-While($line -ne 0)`, `Do-Until($line -le 0)` with the same outcome.
When I tried `Do-Until($line -ne 0)` it stopped after the first run, with Value1 (higher) and Value2(lower) changed. I ran the script 3-4 times and eventually Value2 got to 0.
I guess I have something wrong in the Do-Until(While) statement and I'm not seeing it.

```
$port.WriteLine("R?`r")
$string1 = $port.ReadLine()
$line1 = [int]($string1 -split ",")[11]
if($line1 -ne 0){
    do{
        $port.WriteLine("V45?`r")
        $v45 = [int]$port.ReadLine()+10
        $port.WriteLine("V45,${v45}`r")
        $port.ReadLine()
        $port.WriteLine("RST`r")
        $port.ReadLine()
        $port.ReadLine()
        $port.WriteLine("R?`r")
        $string = $port.ReadLine()
        $line = [int]($string1 -split ",")[11]
    }until($line -eq 0)
}
```

Comment: Output the status of $v45 and $line every iteration to make sure those variables are changing as you expect.  Write-Host "Line: $line V45: $V45"

Comment: the output from Write-Host is `Line: 24 V45: 40` `Line: 24 V45: 50` `Line: 24 V45: 60` and so on. Somehow it doesn't read Line...is a serial interface if I change v45 and then check the Line it does change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading to `$string` but then parsing `$string1`. Rename `$string1` to `$string` on the second line.

`$string = $port.ReadLine()
 $line = [int]($string1 -split ",")[11] #Change this line to $string`

You would benefit from naming your variables in a more meaningful way.

Comment: I knew there was something wrong. I have `$string1` before the loop and was always using one. Now it works. Thank you